# Extracting an an integer value from an xml column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xml, substring

I'm just wondering how I can extract an integer out of an XML column. Currently all the digits are 4 which the below query is able to do. But the number is going to grow to 10,000's soon which will mean 5 digit and this query will not be able to do it. Is there anyway that I can dynamically get any integer out that is next in the middle of `<siteID>` and `</siteID>` from the Xml column. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(msg, patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]</siteID>%',msg),4)  AS DOMAIN
FROM table  a(NOLOCK)
WHERE msg like '<DLR%'
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the [value() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) of the XML data type.

If your XML structure looks like this:

```xml
<DLR>
  <siteID>12345</siteID>
</DLR>
```

Your query would be

```sql
select msg.value('(/DLR/siteID/text())[1]', 'int') as DOMAIN
from dbo.YourTable
```

But it does however not look like you have an XML column at all since `msg like '<DLR%'` is invalid against XML columns.

Then you need to either modify your table so the column is XML or you can cast to XML in your query.

```sql
select cast(msg as xml).value('(/DLR/siteID/text())[1]', 'int') as DOMAIN
from dbo.YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data is not that clean, then XQuery function fn:number is actually quite good at cleaning it for you.  Try this simple demo:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#yourTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #yourTable
CREATE TABLE #yourTable ( rowId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, msg VARCHAR(8000) )

INSERT INTO #yourTable ( msg ) VALUES ( '<DLR_NOTIFICATION><siteid>29   </siteid>trailing tab</DLR_NOTIFICATION>' )
INSERT INTO #yourTable ( msg ) VALUES ( '<DLR_NOTIFICATION><siteid> 101</siteid>leading tab</DLR_NOTIFICATION>' )
INSERT INTO #yourTable ( msg ) VALUES ( '<DLR_NOTIFICATION><siteid>
2001</siteid>carriage return</DLR_NOTIFICATION>' )

INSERT INTO #yourTable ( msg ) VALUES ( '<DLR_NOTIFICATION>
    <kid>204122</kid>
    <siteid> 1234
    </siteid>
    <transid>1************</transid>
    <service>20462</service>
    <mobile>447*******</mobile>
    <msisdntype>IPAlias</msisdntype>
    <operator>
        Three
    </operator>
    <status>100</status>
    <tariff>0000</tariff>
    <billingroute>
        I******
    </billingroute>
    <purpose>IMPULSEPAY DLR NOTIFICATION</purpose>
    <tracking>
        <aff>14_z</aff>
        <param>undefined</param>
        <paramdetails>
            kp=xkpgbadu200000000000000000000000059;
        </paramdetails>
    </tracking>
</DLR_NOTIFICATION>' )

SELECT s.c.value('fn:number(.)', 'INT' ) AS siteid
FROM ( SELECT CAST( msg AS XML ) AS msg FROM #yourTable ) a
    CROSS APPLY a.msg.nodes('DLR_NOTIFICATION/siteid') s(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

If MS SQL Server is what you're using, it supports XPath query within the SELECT statement.  See [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-xml-questions-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/#tenth) for an example and [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899313/select-values-from-xml-field-in-sql-server-2008) an SO question.

This will allow you to extract the numerals from within the xml irrespective of how many digits it contains.  You can then `CONVERT()` it to `int` or whatever as needs be.